# Fetching a table that shares the class name with other tables in HTML parsing using lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to fetch some data from a table of a webpage using lxml. Unable to catch the particular table. I am trying the same approach for another table and it works but cant understand where I am going wrong here.

The table I am trying to fetch shares it's class name with two other tables so I am trying to fetch all and print the different elements of list but I am receiving an empty string.

```py
wiki_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_Siakam'

wiki_page=requests.get(wiki_url)

doc=lxml.html.fromstring(wiki_page.content)

#This ideally should return a list of tables with the specified class names
tables=doc.xpath('//table[@class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"]')

print(tables[0])
```

Expected output is something like:

```
<Element table at 0x271d3a8b958>
```

Actual output is an index error:

```py
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-6665a6637719> in <module>
      6 tables=doc.xpath('//table[@class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"]')
      7 
----> 8 print(tables[0])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: That page doesn't have a table with a class with `jquery-tablesorter`.

Comment: `doc.xpath('//table[@class="wikitable sortable"]')` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The class jquery-tablesorter is set when jquery loads.

Maybe you chose the classes with a browser with javascript but when fetching with requests, jquery won't be executed.

```py
import requests
from lxml import html, etree

wiki_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_Siakam'
wiki_page=requests.get(wiki_url)
doc=html.fromstring(wiki_page.content)

#This ideally should return a list of tables with the specified class names
tables=doc.xpath('//table[@class="wikitable sortable"]')

print(tables[0])
```